# powershell get return status and output to null

Tags: powershell, return

How can I get the return status of a command ran, while outputting any messages to out-null.

Right now I have

`{command} | out-null`

I would like to get the return status `$?` of that command though. Anyway to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Is the command native or an external application?

Comment: @nimizen external, its schtasks

Comment: I'm guessing $LastExitCode will still hold the exit code, can you check?  As a rule of thumb use $? for CMDLets and $LastExitCode for external apps.

Comment: @nimizen Yeah, that works. Thanks! Add that as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's my comment as an answer...
I'm guessing $LastExitCode will still hold the exit code; as a rule of thumb use $? for CMDLets and $LastExitCode for external apps.

Answer (score 0):

> exit $LastExitCode

You will get above return code on windows CLI using  ***echo %errorlevel%***.
You can also return custom error code like this - ***exit 84***